# Condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

This is my problem: I added a column `Cause` to my table. This column contains different conditions (up to here, everything is fine). But since I have a lot of lines for each product, it can have 3 conditions at the same time.

What I'm trying to do is that once it finds a condition, it does not go to the one after (and it is by this order of priority).

I do not know if I was clear, but if you want more explanation do not hesitate to ask me questions

```
Cause = (CASE
            WHEN Four IS NOT NULL THEN 'Retards'
            WHEN (MAX(DateP BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-14') THEN 'stock'
            WHEN Reference = 0  THEN 'respecté'
            WHEN Produit = 2 THEN 'non respecté'
            ELSE 'Erreur'
         END)
```

This is an example of what I want to do:
[image: This is an example of what I want to do]

Comment: The order of the case statements does matter. The first matching row will be the one returned. So I am a bit unsure as to what you are asking;

From MSDN: "The CASE expression evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied."

Comment: @JamesCooke for exmple for the product numbre 1 i returned 10 lines because i have différent command.
SO,if i  have the fields "Four" is not null in the line of the command "X",and the field "reference"=0 in the line of the command "Y",i want 'retards' in my new fields 'cause' because both are for the same product

Comment: sorry i dont understand - can you show me some examples of the sets you receive and what you want to receive?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The CASE expression stops just after the first WHEN..THEN is found. If you want to concatenate labels and check all conditions, you can use multiple CASE expression.

```
(case when Four IS NOT NULL THEN 'Retards' ELSE '' END +
 case when (MAX(DateP) between '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-14') THEN 'stock' ELSE '' END +
 case when Reference = 0  THEN 'respecté' ELSE '' END +
 case when Produit = 2 THEN 'non respecté' ELSE '' END 
) AS Cause
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff why you changed "statement" to "expression"?? CASE is not the expression, CASE is the statement that operates multiples expressions inside.

Comment: The SQL construct that returns a single value in a query is a "case expression".  Some databases do support "case statements" in their scripting language -- similar to `if`s.that operate similarly to `if` statements

Comment: ok, I see the logic, 'case' expression inside the 'select' statement